# How can I determine why Postgres selects a query plan?

Tags: sql, postgresql, optimization

I have a relatively modest query using a two table join in Postgres, but am getting drastically different performance when I run the query in my development environment vs the production environment.

This is the query:

```
select count(seat_id) as avail, ev.event_name, price_code, 
   (case when substring(section_name, 4, 1) = 'A' then substring(section_name, 1, 3)
         when row_name < '9999' then section_name 
         else section_name || 'C' 
   end) as section_name_full, class_name
from tm_availseats3_exp seats join tm_event_map ev on ev.event_name = seats.event_name
where event_sub_type = 'General'
group by ev.event_name, price_code, section_name_full, class_name, row_name
```

The data in the two environments is the same, as are the indexes.  I've run both the query in both environments with "Analyze Explain" and get the following results.

This is fast:

```
HashAggregate  (cost=29061.69..29229.88 rows=7475 width=41) (actual time=662.006..682.448 rows=17444 loops=1)
  Group Key: ev.event_name, seats.price_code, CASE WHEN ("substring"((seats.section_name)::text, 4, 1) = 'A'::text) THEN "substring"((seats.section_name)::text, 1, 3) WHEN ((seats.row_name)::text < '9999'::text) THEN (seats.section_name)::text ELSE ((seats.section_name)::text || 'C'::text) END, seats.class_name, seats.row_name
->  Nested Loop  (cost=1090.79..28949.57 rows=7475 width=41) (actual time=2.267..488.597 rows=110977 loops=1)
    ->  HashAggregate  (cost=784.42..784.44 rows=1 width=51) (actual time=2.076..2.163 rows=61 loops=1)
          Group Key: ev_1.event_name, ev.event_name, ev_1.event_date, ev.event_name_long, ev.event_time, ev.event_day, CASE WHEN ("substring"((ev.event_name)::text, 1, 4) = 'EUCB'::text) THEN 'General'::text ELSE 'Premium'::text END
          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=558.96..784.41 rows=1 width=51) (actual time=0.997..1.967 rows=61 loops=1)
                ->  HashAggregate  (cost=558.68..558.78 rows=10 width=12) (actual time=0.953..1.021 rows=61 loops=1)
                      Group Key: ev_1.event_name, ev_1.event_date
                      ->  Seq Scan on tm_evnt3 ev_1  (cost=0.00..558.63 rows=10 width=12) (actual time=0.035..0.876 rows=61 loops=1)
                            Filter: ("substring"((event_name)::text, 1, 4) = 'EUCB'::text)
                            Rows Removed by Filter: 1981
                ->  Index Scan using idx_tm_evnt3__event_date on tm_evnt3 ev  (cost=0.28..22.54 rows=1 width=43) (actual time=0.006..0.011 rows=1 loops=61)
                      Index Cond: (event_date = ev_1.event_date)
                      Filter: (("substring"((event_name)::text, 1, 4) <> 'PARK'::text) AND ("substring"((event_name)::text, 1, 5) <> 'PROMO'::text) AND ("substring"((event_name)::text, length((event_name)::text), 1) <> 'P'::text) AND (CASE WHEN ("substring"((event_name)::text, 1, 4) = 'EUCB'::text) THEN 'General'::text ELSE 'Premium'::text END = 'General'::text))
                      Rows Removed by Filter: 5
    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on tm_availseats3_exp seats  (cost=306.36..27996.93 rows=7475 width=41) (actual time=0.194..2.352 rows=1819 loops=61)
          Recheck Cond: ((event_name)::text = (ev.event_name)::text)
          Heap Blocks: exact=12875
          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on tm_availseats3_exp_on_event  (cost=0.00..304.50 rows=7475 width=0) (actual time=0.168..0.168 rows=1819 loops=61)
                Index Cond: ((event_name)::text = (ev.event_name)::text)
Planning time: 0.498 ms
Execution time: 700.538 ms
```

And this is really, really slow:

```
HashAggregate  (cost=1083030.39..1083267.27 rows=10528 width=41) (actual time=107897.847..107918.705 rows=17444 loops=1)
  Group Key: ev.event_name, seats.price_code, CASE WHEN ("substring"((seats.section_name)::text, 4, 1) = 'A'::text) THEN "substring"((seats.section_name)::text, 1, 3) WHEN ((seats.row_name)::text < '9999'::text) THEN (seats.section_name)::text ELSE ((seats.section_name)::text || 'C'::text) END, seats.class_name, seats.row_name
  ->  Hash Join  (cost=795.21..1082872.47 rows=10528 width=41) (actual time=47773.210..107704.968 rows=110977 loops=1)
    Hash Cond: ((seats.event_name)::text = (ev.event_name)::text)
    ->  Seq Scan on tm_availseats3_exp seats  (cost=0.00..1052862.73 rows=7727373 width=41) (actual time=3352.769..103536.131 rows=3609106 loops=1)
    ->  Hash  (cost=795.20..795.20 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=2.364..2.364 rows=61 loops=1)
          Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 3kB
          ->  Subquery Scan on ev  (cost=795.18..795.20 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=2.107..2.292 rows=61 loops=1)
                ->  HashAggregate  (cost=795.18..795.19 rows=1 width=51) (actual time=2.104..2.169 rows=61 loops=1)
                      Group Key: ev_2.event_name, ev_1.event_name, ev_2.event_date, ev_1.event_name_long, ev_1.event_time, ev_1.event_day, CASE WHEN ("substring"((ev_1.event_name)::text, 1, 4) = 'EUCB'::text) THEN 'General'::text ELSE 'Premium'::text END
                      ->  Nested Loop  (cost=568.96..795.16 rows=1 width=51) (actual time=0.998..1.987 rows=61 loops=1)
                            ->  HashAggregate  (cost=568.68..568.78 rows=10 width=12) (actual time=0.942..1.018 rows=61 loops=1)
                                  Group Key: ev_2.event_name, ev_2.event_date
                                  ->  Seq Scan on tm_evnt3 ev_2  (cost=0.00..568.63 rows=10 width=12) (actual time=0.039..0.864 rows=61 loops=1)
                                        Filter: ("substring"((event_name)::text, 1, 4) = 'EUCB'::text)
                                        Rows Removed by Filter: 1981
                            ->  Index Scan using idx_tm_evnt3__event_date on tm_evnt3 ev_1  (cost=0.28..22.62 rows=1 width=43) (actual time=0.006..0.011 rows=1 loops=61)
                                  Index Cond: (event_date = ev_2.event_date)
                                  Filter: (("substring"((event_name)::text, 1, 4) <> 'PARK'::text) AND ("substring"((event_name)::text, 1, 5) <> 'PROMO'::text) AND ("substring"((event_name)::text, length((event_name)::text), 1) <> 'P'::text) AND (CASE WHEN ("substring"((event_name)::text, 1, 4) = 'EUCB'::text) THEN 'General'::text ELSE 'Premium'::text END = 'General'::text))
                                  Rows Removed by Filter: 5
Planning time: 0.482 ms
Execution time: 107936.927 ms
```

It's fairly clear to me that the problem is that the second execution plan starts the query with Seq Scan on what is the much larger of the two tables involved here, but I don't have any idea why it doesn't create the same plan.

Is the Postgres query planner deterministic?  Is there any way to provide it a hint as to the query plan it should use?

Comment: Check if `tm_availseats3_exp_on_event` index is created on the "slow" machine, if not, then create it, and run explain analyze again.

Comment: Try to perform `VACUUM ANALYZE <table_name>;` for each table, appearing in query

Comment: Using the VACUUM ANALYZE was the correct strategy.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ildar Musin commented, the correct approach is to make sure that the statistics are up-to-date on all the databases.  My understanding was that this was happening automatically, but was not.

VACUUM ANALYZE was able to get the performance of the slow-running query to be very similar to the faster one.